# Cannot call a method?

Tags: java

I have a Game class and a TestGame class, I'm trying to call a method from Game to TestGame.

TestGame.java

```
public class TestGame {

    Players ceri = new Players("Ceri", 1);
    Players harry = new Players("Harry", 1);
    Players lewis = new Players("Lewis", 1);
    Players kwok = new Players("Kwok", 1);
    Players james = new Players("James", 1);
    Players matthew = new Players("Matthew", 1);


    Game league = new Game("League Table");

    league.addplayer(ceri);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

and Game.java

```
public class Game {

    private String name;

    public Game(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addPlayer(Players obj){

    }
}
```

I get red lines underneath `league.addPlayer` for some reason.

Comment: You don't even have a constructor with two arguments.

Comment: "I'm probably going to get down voted for this.." then fix your question so you won't. It sounds like you already know what's wrong with it, which is a good start.

Comment: `league.addplayer(ceri);` needs to be inside an appropriate method of some sort - it currently isn't so it's a compile time error

Comment: make the objects in the main method.

Comment: Further to the answers that have been posted: You've got a method called `addPlayer` defined in `Game`, but you're trying to call `addplayer`. Capitalisation matters, those two are not the same. You'll need to capitalise that `p` as well as address the other problems with that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`league.addplayer(ceri);` is code, not initializer.

You need to put it inside a method or inside an initalizer block.

In this case put it inside your `main` method.

Comment: In this specific case, it won't work in a `static` initialization block, but well in an _instance_ initialization block.

Comment: The `Players` and `Game` variables should also be `static`, as you would be referencing them from a `static context`

Comment: @MatiCicero Better to create an instance of the class and invoke the methods on it rather than just making everything static unnecessarily.

Comment: Where is that written in the question? I see no indication of it. The `main` method? As far as I can see, it's empty, so it's not a good clue.

Comment: @JonK I agree it would be the best option, I'm just giving extra tips if the OP's gonna follow @Tim B advice and move the `addPlayer` method to the `main`

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to move all of these lines to the main() method:

```
Players ceri = new Players("Ceri", 1);
Game league = new Game("League Table");
league.addplayer(ceri);
```

If you move only the last one, the *league* and *ceri* variables won't be accessible, as the main method is a static method and these variables would be instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

All of your `Players` (and `Game`) are declared inside the class body. This makes them global variables with default level access. Something to note in addition to Tim B's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your code **inside** the main block.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    league.addplayer(ceri);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will give you a compiler error saying "Cannot reference non-static variable 'league' from a static context" - or something to that effect.